# Isn't the transition at the critical point always a continuous phase transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

At page 145 of *Chaikin and Lubensky's Principles of Condensed matter physics*, there are [two figures](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=P9YjNjzr9OIC&pg=PA77&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) 4.0.1(a) and 4.0.1(b). Figure (a) shows that at $T=T_c$, there is a continuous transition (the order parameter changes continuously) while figure (b) shows that at $T=T_c$ there is a discontinuous transition (the order parameter jumps discontinuously).

*But isn't the transition at the critical point always continuous? How would the second situation as described in diagram (b) (the order parameter suddenly jumping to a nonzero value from a zero value) arise at the critical point?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example: Water-ice transition. If you take the density to be your order parameter, the density drops discontinuously at $0^\text{o}$ C.

A second simple example: An Ising model in an external field at $T=0$. If the external field, $H$, is positive, the magnetization, $M$, is $+1$. If the external field is negative, $M=-1$. Clearly $M$ changes discontinuously at $H=0$.

A third, more complex example: A 2D Ising model below the critical temperature. If you don't like the fact that the above transition takes place at $T=0$, in 2D the Ising model spontaneously magnetizes even at small nonzero temperatures. In this case, just above $H=0$, $M=M_0$, and just below $H=0$, $M=-M_0$. $M$ jumps discontinuously.

In general, a critical point is where *any* phase transition occurs, continuous or discontinuous. It refers to the combination of parameters that sit on the boundary between one phase and another. So a critical temperature is the temperature that separates two phases (Any phases! Any type of transition!) and a critical field is the field that separates two phases, etc.

If you think about Landau theory, a first-order (discontinuous) phase transition happens when the Landau free energy has two local minima, and the global minima changes from one value to another. Consider the following graph, where $\phi$ is the order parameter and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Landau free energy.

[image: First order phase transition Landau energy]

Here, just above $T_c$, the Landau free energy has two local minima, at $\phi=0$ and $\phi>0$. Above $T_c$, $\phi=0$ is the global minimum. At $T_c$, the two minima have the same value for the Landau free energy. Below $T_c$, the minimum with $\phi>0$ has the lowest Landau free energy. Thus, above $T_c$, the system will have $\phi=0$, and below $T_c$ the system will have $\phi>0$ discontinuously.

Comment: But in the phase diagram of water, there is a critical point only on the liquid-gas coexistence curve. There is no other critical point. $0^0$ is not the critical point. @JahanClaes

Comment: @SRS If you plot the density as a function of temperature at fixed pressure, you will find that the density jumps discontinuously at $0^\text{o}$. It's true that this point is not "the critical point of water", since people usually use the phrase "critical point" to refer to the end of the liquid-gas coexistence curve when talking about water.

Comment: @SRS But you can't deny that a first-order phase transition is happening at $T=0$.

Comment: @SRS And more generally, people use the phrase "critical point" to refer to any point where a phase transition is happening. The term is overloaded.

Comment: @SRS: Even simpler example: Ising model in a magnetic field. When you tune $H$ from positive to negative, the magnetization abruptly flips from $M$ to $-M$. This is clearly a discontinuous change at $H=0$.

Comment: So the $T_c$ in figure (b) is actually the first order transition temperature. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Another example, maybe more satisfactory, is the Potts model. This is a generalization of the Ising model allowing for $q\geq 2$ different spin states. In this model, the phase transition as the temperature crosses $T_c$ is of first order when $q$ is large enough ($q\geq 5$ in dimension $2$, $q\geq 3$ in higher dimensions).

Comment: @JahanClaes I generally see the phrase "triple point" used if they are trying to make sure to make it clear.  I usually see "critical point" as the point where it transitions into supercritical fluid.

Comment: @SRS yes, that's what I'm saying. $T_c$ is just the temperature at which the phase transition happens either way.

Comment: @JMac Critical points and triple points are different. See the diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics))

Comment: @JahanClaes If you include the point that $T_c$ can refer to the first order transition temperature in your answer, I can accept th answer because that was the main point of confusion. Thanks.

Comment: @SRS Edited, hope that makes sense.